# Often cannot access the magnifying glass for text insertion on iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, text-input

Often, though not always, I am unable to bring up the text insertion magnifying glass on certain web pages by performing a long tap within the text field. Usually, doing a long tap (holding a single finger down) within a text field will cause the magnifying glass to appear which facilitates accurate placement of the text insertion cursor.  But there are times when I hold my finger down to place the insertion within a text entry field, usually to make corrections, and absolutely nothing happens!

Usually it works like it is supposed to, but it seems that I'm finding more and more often that at times, and especially on certain web pages, I am only able to insert text in an existing line of text by doing a quick, hard tap, usually somewhere after where I wanted to place it, backspace to the point I wanted to make the change at, make the change, and retype everything I just backspaced over.

This is really frustrating, and it didn't used to be a problem at all. Is it possible that some of the more elaborate scripting found on some web pages might be interfering with proper operation of iOS's text insertion regime?

Comment: What are some of the webpages that you are having a problem with? Also entirely possible it is not the iPad/Safari, but, as you say "some web pages might be interfering with proper operation of iOS's text insertion."